# How to run unit tests only for a class in a Hybris project through Command line?

Tags: java, junit, ant, sap-commerce-cloud

Many times due to some errors in project or mis-configuration in eclipse, Junits fails to run for a class. How one can execute such unittests from command line without wasting effort.

Answer (score 1):

Many times due to some errors in project or mis-configuration in eclipse, Junits fails to run for a class. While working in a hybris project, we have an option to execute our junits from command line as well.

1. Go to platform directory.
2. Set ant environment.
3. Execute test with below script:

   ```sh
   ant unittests -Dtestclasses.suppress.junit.tenant=true -Dtest="**fully-qualified test class name**"
   ```

   or

   ```sh
   ant unittests -Dtestclasses.suppress.junit.tenant=true -Dtest="de.hybris.platform.acceleratorfacades.cart.action.populator.AcceleratorCartEntryActionPopulatorTest"
   ```
4. Then one can check report generated at below directory.

   Report dir : D:\HybrisSetup\Code\hybris\log/junit

   [image]

Comment: You can also skip -Dtestclasses.suppress.junit.tenant=true but it speeds up the execution. I did not know this parameter. Thanks!